# how to mock a scope from a directive instead of a controller in angular unit-test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, karma-runner

so i am familiar with the concept  of mocking a $scope and controller with a $controller constructor

```
var scope = rootScope.$new();
it('should contain a testVar value at "test var home"', function(){
    homeCtrl = $controller('homeCtrl', {
        $scope: homeScope,
        $rootScope: rootScope
    })

    expect(homeScope.testVar).toBe('test var home');
})
```

is there a way to mock a directive in the same way? both a directive and its controller?

```
//mock coding
var scope = rootScope.$new();
it('should contain a testVar value at "test var home"', function(){
    homeDir = $directive('homeCtrl', {
        $scope: homeScope,
        $elem: angular.element('<div....</div>'),
        $att: {}
        $modelViewController: angular.element().controller('ngModel')
    })
            homeCtrl = homeDir.$getController();
    expect(homeScope.testVar).toBe('test var home');
})
```

the question meant to target directives, how to test them? how to extract their components? from what i know if I had a function on directive, i need to attach it to a scope or else if it belongs to directive then the function is un-testable. so if i want to use the scope during the test how to inject the scope into a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I set up directive-specs is

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var htmlString = '' +
        '<my-directive some-attr="value">' +
        '</my-directive>'
        ;
    element = angular.element(htmlString)
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));
```

Basically I compile a HTML string that declares my directive and run the resulting function with my injected scope. Then I use JQuery (or JQueryLite) to interact with the `element` or do assertions directly on the `scope`

Comment: thanks, I tested this out last night and it worked, but thanks anyway

Comment: If you have a file that does not have a templateUrl is there additional functionality required to get the scope?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood that question